# ElasticSearch in Python: Conjunction between separate terms queries

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Maybe my question is a bit unclear, but I will give it a shot since I am quite inexperienced with ElasticSeach. What I have are indexed documents in the following format:

```
{"field1": "something", "field2": "nothing", "text_filed": "some_text"}
```

What I want to do, is run queries such that the `field1` and `field2` will be used for `terms` matching as a `filter`, and the `text_field` will be used as the standard query. My question is about the `filter`. Because my inputs are going to be in the form:

```
field1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
field2 = [["one", "one1"], ["two", "2two", "two2"], ...]
query = "whatever"
```

I want to filter all documents that have `1` in `field1` and either `one` or `one1` in `field2`, then, all documents that have `2` in `field1` and either `two`, `2two` or `two2` as `field2` and so on...

For me it is pretty clear how to do basic filtering across both `field1` and `field2`, but I do not know how to combine them. Preferably, I would like to know how can I achieve this using Python DSL.

Looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to combined some [boolean](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) logic.

The request body should look like this:

```
{
    query: {
        bool: {
            must: [
                {
                    bool: {
                        must: [
                            {
                                term: {
                                    field1: "1"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                fuzzy: {
                                    field2: {
                                        value: "one",
                                        fuzziness: 1
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    bool: {
                        must: [
                            {
                                term: {
                                    field1: "2"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                fuzzy: {
                                    field2: {
                                        value: "two",
                                        fuzziness: 1
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that each boolean "cluster" has to be conditioned on one number due to elastic [array](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) type being flattened.

- this answer is conditioned on fields being of the default types when indexing, if you have a `nested` field in your mapping this will not necessarily work.